I have this error League\OAuth2\Client\Provider\Exception\IdentityProviderException invalid_grant
the program is work well for years and now this is the error when we send a email.
I have generate the token 2 years ago
I try to generate another token but the response of get_oauth_token.php is empty
I  dont know that is the problem. I put in the web folder of my application that was created from a yii2 framework.
I try to generate another token but the response of get_oauth_token.php is empty
I  dont know that is the problem. I put in the web folder of my application that was created from a Yii2 framework.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
